# Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI list not updating after file delete

Tags: android

I am querying MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI for all music files. It works just fine but whenever i want to delete a music file from my sdCard, the list won't update. Any idea how to update the list?

here's my code for getting music files:

```
    Cursor cursor;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";


    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, {"*"}, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String songName = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));


                String path = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                int albumId = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                songs.add(new SongItem(albumName, albumId, path, songname));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly added files are added to the cursor and deleted file will not be removed actually.

For that we need to check whether the file is available or not. If not available delete that from database using content provider

This is how i fixed my issue:

```
        Uri files= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;    
        Cursor cursor= managedQuery(files, STAR, null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int r= 0; r<cursor.getCount(); r++, cursor.moveToNext()){
            int i = cursor.getInt(0);
         File file = new File(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));

            if(file.exists()){
                // keep files if it is empty
                list.add("Keeping : " + cursor.getString(2) + " : id(" + i + ")");
            }else{
                // delete any play-lists with a data length of '0'
                Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, i);
                getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                list.add("Deleted : " + cursor.getString(2) + " : id(" + i + ")");
            }
        }       
        cursor.close();
```